# Right Timezone - Wrong Time - DST (Debian)

Tags: debian, timezone

After the Daylight Saving Time (last Sunday) the "date" output is wrong. 
I run `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, set the timezone (again) to Europe/Athens, and it still displays the wrong time.

After `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` it outputs:

```
Current default time zone: 'Europe/Athens'
Local time is now:      Wed Mar 30 12:04:07 EEST 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Wed Mar 30 09:04:07 UTC 2016.
```

But the **real time** in Athens now is **13:04:07** due to DST. I am also confirming the real current time through *www.timeanddate.com*

`date` also outputs:

```
Wed Mar 30 12:04:77 EEST 2016
```

I am running Debian GNU/Linux 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your clock is one hour late - UTC to EEST difference is 3 hours, so the tzdata correctly converts your 09:04 UTC into 12:04 EEST. Move your clock forward by one hour, e.g. by running `ntpdate pool.ntp.org`.

Comment: Thanks mate. I apt-get installed `ntp` and now it gives the correct time!